# Javascript alert test not working

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I should be sleeping but this is really bugging me. I can't get a simple javascript alert box to display in my asp.net project. Hopefully someone can see what I'm doing wrong. My test page is this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="JSTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="Proj.JSTest" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Header" runat="server">

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Working");
    });



</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

The masterpage is pretty standard as well. Here's the header part of it (which I figure is the key bit)

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>



     <%--<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script> --%>

    <link href="App_Themes/Default/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Header" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

I know I must be missing something obvious - probably just need sleep :D. But if anyone can see why this isn't working, that would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try putting it in another script tag, but without the `src` attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Working");
    });

</script>
```

Or put it in a separate file and include the file using the src attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="myJSFile.js"></script>
```

Comment: /facepalm. Thank you, that's fixed it.

Comment: No Problem. Now you can go to sleep :)

Answer (score 3):

You  are encosing document ready inside the script tag which references jquery. Put that in another script tag like below.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Working");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be like...

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript" ></script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Working");
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you got a bug in javascript code, [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) and Web inspector will be your best friend.

You can see what's wrong in the page. It might that jQuery library not loaded, the produced HTML contains error, missing tags, etc.

Using [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) or Web Inspector, you can know what is wrong in the page.

Answer (score 0):

include that script within

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Working");
    });

</script>
```